# get error Could not find definition for entity name

Tags: freemarker, ofbiz

can any one help me pleaze to find a solution for this error
i want to get the list of service so  my code is

```
public static List<GenericValue> TW_getListService(Delegator delegator) {

    try {
        List<GenericValue> twService = EntityQuery.use(delegator).from("twService").queryList();


        return twService;
    } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
        Debug.logError(e, "Error looking up ProdCatalogCategories for prodCatalog with id " , module);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you want a list of services in OFBiz, why not using the OOTB feature, eg: https://demo-trunk.ofbiz.apache.org/webtools/control/ServiceList ?

Comment: thanks the probleme came from cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probleme came from cache i just delete cache and it work